# MVC Controller Organization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've inherited a project in which I'm the fifth proverbial 'cook in the kitchen'. The project is too mature for extensive changes on my timeline, but I'm thinking I can at least get rid of some of the "where was that code again!?" issues I'm having.

All of the controllers are dumped in the same Controller folder, but there are enough with similiar names to be a bit cumbersome. Additionally some of these controllers are solely for partial views. The admin page for instance has its own controller, but each of the four tabs on its view have their own model/view/controller. What are some recommended approaches I should take to get this under control?

Comment: Sub folders in the controllers folder?

Comment: Thats where I'm wanting to go, but I seem to remember having issues with some of my tool sets recognizing associated models/views/controllers

Comment: You should keep everything that controller a view in the same controller. If you have multiple controllers for the same view, you are doing something wrong, and messing with the MVC Pattern.

Comment: I agree Fal, but I didn't start this project, and cant realistically change it at this juncture. To be clear though, each partial has a dedicated controller. The view only has one of its own.

Though there is a controller being used as a business logic class in here too.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz The issue i'm having is the views can't be found by the controller if I do the corresponding subdirectory in the view folder

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to organize your MVC project, I find `Areas` an invaluable way to keep things from getting out of control.

It might mean changing some of your paths, but I'll leave it to you to determine the value to your particular project.

Have a read of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Before I dive into attempting to implement this, would it cause any interruptions to query strings? I don't see that it would but worth asking.

Comment: You can use the AttributeRouting table to make sure your paths don't change. The query strings don't care where the controllers are.